# Show layout guide lines in Eclipse Graphical Layout Editor

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface

How do I turn it on... I do not see Layout lines or TableLayout lines and it is hard to organize elements.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the editor hasn't got this feature built in. Sorry. You could always put in a Feature Request here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request